# Deleting Rows that Match a Criteria Efficiently with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to cycle through a sheet and delete all rows where a certain column's value matches my criteria. So at the moment, I use a normal for loop, and restart it every time I hit and entry and delete a row, so that I don't miss anything:

```
Function DeleteAllGroupData(ByVal groupName As String)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

GoAgain:
    lRow = data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lRow
        If data.Range("B" & i).Value = groupName Then
            data.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            GoTo GoAgain
        End If
    Next i

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

My question though, is there a more efficient way of doing this? Where I don't have to restart the for loop every time I hit a delete?

Comment: Filter then delete the visible rows.

Comment: You shouldn't be deleting rows in a function - use a sub instead

Comment: But if you loop backwards: `For i = lRow to 1 step -1` you do not need to restart the loop

Comment: @urdearboy. Why?

Comment: @CornelVerster see the first bullet point under "More Information" from Microsoft documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using filter then delete the visible rows as said Scott, for example :

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range(Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1").End(xlDown)), Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).End(xlToLeft)).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Criteria" _
, "Criteria", "Criteria", "Criteria", "="), Operator:= _
xlFilterValues

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Rows("1:100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

Also your code without go to would be like that :

```
Function DeleteAllGroupData(ByVal groupName As String)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer


    lRow = data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lRow
        If data.Range("B" & i).Value = groupName Then
            data.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            i= i - 1
        End If
    Next i

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: Looping backwards as suggested (i= lRow to 1 step -1) might just be more elegant than inserting the i = i -1

Comment: @CornelVerster glad that we could help you !

Answer (score 0):

### Union

If you did need to loop you are better off deleting rows outside of your loop. i.e. have your loop gather up a collection (`Union`) of rows to be deleted and once the loop is complete, delete all the rows at once. This will be much faster than your current approach *(although if you don't need to loop the filter method is optimal here)*

---

```
Sub delete_with_loop(groupName as String)

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim DeleteMe As Range, xCell As Range, lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each xCell In ws.Range("B1:B" & lr)
    If xCell = groupName Then
        If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, xCell)
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = xCell
        End If
    End If
Next xCell

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
    DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete
End If


End Sub
```